# Equation is not centered inside the diamond node

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-node, flow-charts, tikz-positioning

Here is my code:

```
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, 
minimum width=2cm, 
minimum height=1cm, 
text centered, 
draw=black, 
fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (14.5,13)[decision,text centered, text width=1cm] {$$\sum_{k=1}^{N} A_k^\dagger A_k\stackrel{?}{=}1$$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This is my output:
[image]

How to put this equation in the middle without changing the size of the diamond?

---

After the comment of @mickep, I tried with single `$` and with `\displaystyle` but still it did not fit in the diamond:

[image]

Comment: Does it work better if you use single dollars and add `\displaystyle` after the first one?

Comment: no unfortunately, I edited my question according to the your command

Comment: Please note that `\tikzstyle` is deprecated. Have a look at `\tikzset` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{
  decision/.style = {
    diamond, 
    minimum width=2cm, 
    %minimum height=1cm, 
    draw=black, 
    fill=green!30,
  },
  arrow/.style = {thick,->,>=stealth},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (14.5,13) [decision] {%
    $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{N} A_k^\dagger A_k^{\vphantom{\dagger}}\overset{?}{=}1$%
   };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please, note that `\tikzstyle` has been deprecated for a few years.